# \MakeTextLowercase not working with \cref

Tags: sectioning, small-caps, classicthesis, cleveref

I'm using `cleveref` and `classicthesis`. `classicthesis` defines section headings to use small caps and uses `\MakeTextLowercase` to achieve this. However, when using the `capitalize` option for `cleveref`, the first letter of the reference is still set as a capital letter; it seems that `\MakeTextLowercase` somehow ignores it.

Here's an MWE without `\classicthesis`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
\titleformat{\section}{\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}


\begin{document} 

\section{\label{sec:foo}foo}
\section{Code for \protect\cref{sec:foo}}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output (ignore the fact that the section numbers are not set in caps `;)`):

[image: output]

Comment: Add `\crefname{section}{section}{sections}` and use `\Cref` when you want a capital initial.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! I realize I could do that (or just skip `capitalize` option of `cleveref`), but I'd like to keep all references in normal text capitalized and I have used `\cref` throughout my thesis. A bit of search and replace could of course fix this, but it seems counter-intuitive that I have to use `\Cref` throughout the document, which I understand is meant for the beginning of sentences only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the names for `\cref` so that they use a macro that can be neutralized when `\spacedlowsmallcaps` is in force.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{%
  \textls[80]{\let\crefuc\@firstofone\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\crefuc}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\section}{\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\crefname{section}{\crefuc{s}ection}{\crefuc{s}ections}


\begin{document}

\section{\label{sec:foo}foo}
\section{Code for \cref{sec:foo}}

Here's a reference to \cref{sec:foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]